# Wave Equation in a Rectangle

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to work through this question about the wave equation and I just don't know what to do.

Solve the wave equation in the rectangle 
$R=\{(x,y):0<x<1, 0<y<3\}\;$,
with homogenous Dirichlet conditions on the boundary and initial conditions
$u(x,y,0) \equiv xy(3-y)(1-x)\;$
and
$u_t(x,y,0) \equiv 0$.

Thank you in advance for the help.

edit for more general example:

Solve the wave equation in the rectangle $R=\{(x,y):0<x<a, 0<y<b\}\;$, with homogenous Dirichlet conditions on the boundary, and the initial conditions $u(x,y,0) \equiv xy(b-y)(a-x)\;$ and $u_t(x,y,0) \equiv 0$.

Comment: Does the PDE be $u_{tt}=u_{xx}+u_{yy}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a set of modes of the rectangle?    These are solutions to the wave equation without regard to the initial conditions and are of the form $f(x,y)e^{i\omega t}$.  If not, do you have a set for the square?

If you do, you need to expand your $u(x,y,0)$ in these modes.  They tend to be numbered $u_{mn}(x,y)$ where $m$ is the number of half waves in the $x$ direction and $n$ is the number in the $y$ direction.  You are looking for a set of coefficients $a_{mn}$ so the solution $u(x,y,t)=a_{mn}u_{mn}e^{i \omega_{mn}t}$There is probably a proof that the modes are orthogonal, in which case you can just do like a Fourrier expansion.  $a_{mn}=\int_{rectangle}u(x,y,0)u_{mn}(x,y)dxdy$  This only works if the modes are orthogonal.

Comment: I have a more general example of the question that I edited in the above and if you could help me work through that example it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Steve:  the new version is identical to the old except for changing 3 to a and 1 to b.  What are the modes?  I would think they are something like $u_{mn}(x,y)\sin \pi mx \sin \frac {n\pi y}3 e^{i \omega_{mn} t}$ with an equation to calculate $\omega_{mn}$ from $m, n$.  Just like a Fourrier expansion, you can multiply the modes by the given $u$ to get the expansion because they are orthogonal.

Comment: I know it is identical, I thought it might help though. I do not know the modes, I was only given what is in the question above, no more. Thank you for the help any way.

Comment: I worked something out I think is correct, thank you for all your help.